# How to share specific 1 card view of activity from Android App programmatically like Google Analytics App

Tags: android, android-layout, screenshot, android-cardview

I am working on an android app of social network and i am stuck at one place.
I want to share specific card view from an activity to facebook or whatsapp wherever user wants to share as an image like google analytics app.
check screenshot below

[image: Suppose i want to share top 2 cards then i can share like this]

Suppose i want to share top 2 card then i can share like this to whatsapp or fb whever i want

1. First card
   [image]
2. Second card
   [image]

First i thought to take screenshot of app and share it to user's social app but it doesn't match to requirements and i have no idea how can we achieve this.

Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: take screenshot of view and share this bitmap using intent.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share a 'Card' to other Apps, however you share a Bitmap (Screenshot) of the Card...

Here's how to do it - 
Create a method like below -

```
public Bitmap ViewShot(View v) {
        int height = v.getHeight();
        int width = v.getWidth();
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas (b);
        v.layout(0, 0 , v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
    }
```

Pass the CardView in the View parameter of ViewShot like -

```
Bitmap screenshot = ViewShot(myCardView);
```

Now you can save that Bitmap to a Temp file & share it with other app!

Comment: when i pass my cardview in method it sayt width and height cannot be 0 !!

Comment: @chiragpatel please share cardview layout or try setting height & width explicitly & not as wrap content!

Answer (score 0):

Create an image and sent it via intent.  An easy way to create a bitmap of a view is to create a bitmap object with width and height equal to that of the view, create a Canvas for that bitmap, and call the view's onDraw function passing in that Canvas.  That will make the View draw itself to the Bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share specific data of that card, my suggestion is [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links). I think this is what you are looking for. You can create a dynamic link for specific page of your app and share the link via whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a Project where my task was to create a business card using XML and share the card on any social media app or mail
Here's the code that worked for me.

```
    public class BusinessCard extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button share;
    CardView cardView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_business_card);

        share=findViewById(R.id.share);
        cardView=findViewById(R.id.visitingCard);



        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Bitmap screenshot = ViewShot(cardView);

            }
        });


    }

    public Bitmap ViewShot(View v) {
        int height = v.getHeight();
        int width = v.getWidth();
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas (b);
        v.layout(0, 0 , v.getLayoutParams().width=750, v.getLayoutParams().height=700);
        v.draw(c);

        Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                b, "Title", null);
        Uri imageUri =  Uri.parse(path);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select"));

        return b;
    }

  
}
```

XML layout(Code):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/purple_200">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/visitingCard"
        android:backgroundTint="#BCB14F"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/gray"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/e_removebg_preview"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp">
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="User Name"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="CEO"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Number     :"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="+919876543210"/>
                </LinearLayout>




                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="email         :"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="www.googleuser@gmail.com"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="website     :"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="userwebsite.com"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3790 Las Vegas Blvd, South"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Las Vegas,Nevada ,United Status, 897845"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Share">

    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this will be helpful to you